# Number of different normalized inner products?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $u,v\in\{0,1\}^n$ be $0-1$ vectors with $n$ components.

Let $I=\langle u,v \rangle$. Clearly $I$ can take values in $\{0,1,\dots,n-1,n\}$.

How many different values can $$I'=\frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle\langle v,v \rangle}}$$ take?

What does the value change if $u,v\in\{-1,1\}^n$?

The question is essentially, how many different angles can one make?

Comment: When you write, "length $n$", it appears you mean "with $n$ components". I note that $I'$ is the cosine of the angle between $u$ and $v$, so you are asking, how many different angles can be formed by pairs of your kind of vector. Have you tried calculating it for small values of $n$, and then consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: Interesting way to look at it as angles. That seems right question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u$ have $x$ ones and $v$ have $y$ ones. For each combination of $x,y\in [1,n]$, the numerator can take up the values between $\max(0,x+y-n)$ and $\min(x,y)$ (minimum and maximum overlap). $x$ and $y$ commmute, so you can order them $x\leq y$ and the upper constraint becomes $x$. However, a single denominator can be reached with different combinations of $x$ and $y$, because you can rearrange prime factors (2*6=4*3 and similar). Additionally, the denominator may or may not be an integer and if it is, it may cancel with the numerator.

I'd look at $(I')^2$ to work with rational numbers, and run some simulations. A nice analytical solution doesn't seem likely.

Short python code to tackle the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from fractions import Fraction as Q

#generates the squares of the numbers
def makeall(n):
    all_f=set()
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        for y in range(1,x+1):
            for z in range(max(0,x+y-n),min(x,y)+1):
                all_f.add(Q(z*z,x*y))

    print('n={}:count={} '.format(n,len(all_f)),', '.join([str(f) for f in all_f]))


if len(sys.argv)>1:
    makeall(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Example output for `n=4`:

```
n=4:count=9  0, 1, 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 4/9, 1/6, 2/3, 1/3
```

The sequence seems to be `1,3,6,9,16,22,35,47,61,75,102,...`.

And no, it is *not* in the `oeis` database. The sequence starts off similar to $n^2$, it turns out that for first 50 values, it fits quite nicely to $0.147 x^{2.74}$ (due to three-stage for loop, the exponent is obviously below 3, and it must be above 2 because the number of numerators goes as $O(n)$ and the number of denominators goes at least as $O(n)$.

---

EDIT: for $({-1,1})$ vectors, the answer is straight-forward. The denominator is always $n$. The numerator is a sum of $n$ terms of $\pm 1$. That's always between $+n$ and $-n$ in increments by $2$. So, $n+1$ different fractions. For $n=3$, these are 3/3, 1/3,-1/3,-3/3.

---

Table:

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 9
5 16
6 22
7 35
8 47
9 61
10 75
11 102
12 124
13 160
14 191
15 228
16 265
17 321
18 368
19 441
20 502
21 571
22 642
23 740
24 823
25 924
26 1022
27 1130
28 1233
29 1376
30 1493
31 1660
32 1809
33 1971
34 2130
35 2312
36 2475
37 2698
38 2896
39 3117
40 3327
41 3603
42 3829
43 4138
44 4415
45 4708
46 4997
47 5363
48 5671
49 6033
50 6366
51 6736
52 7087
53 7528
54 7903
55 8344
56 8749
57 9195
58 9628
59 10161
60 10604
61 11184
62 11713
63 12273
64 12814
65 13409
66 13934
67 14614
68 15226
69 15883
70 16501
71 17262
72 17918
73 18733
74 19478
75 20253
76 21014
77 21862
78 22611
79 23553
80 24385
81 25286
82 26155
83 27191
84 28076
85 29100
86 30063
87 31106
88 32083
89 33262
90 34252
91 35416
92 36500
93 37675
94 38795
95 40037
96 41138
97 42499
98 43717
99 45016
```

Comment: So you are saying there is only $O(n^2)$ distinct possibilities in $\{0,1\}$ case?

Comment: I mean $O(n^3)$?

Comment: Yes. At most. Actually, more like $O(n^{2.74})$ because you get duplicate fractions when numerator and denominator have a common divisor. This could probably be investigated more carefully with number theory (what is the probability that two numbers within some range are coprime).

Comment: Could you calculate data for more $n$ and table them?

Comment: @Turbo First 100 values added.